# Who wants to visit whom?

Tags: meaning

In this sentence:

好久没有看望萧乾老人了，怕干扰他翻译和写作，怕影响他休养生息，但心里却常惦念着他。

I think 好久没有看望萧乾老人了, = 萧乾好久没有看望老人了， but I'm not certain and I don't know why I think this. Is there a rule of syntax being followed here?

Could it be read '老人很久没有看望萧乾了，'?

I think '怕干扰他翻译和写作' means '萧乾怕干扰自己的翻译和写作工作，‘ but I suppose it could be '老人怕干扰他。。。‘

Who does ‘看望，怕，休养生息， 惦念‘？Is that clear from this sentence?

Answer (score 3):

> Who does ‘看望，怕，休养生息， 惦念‘？Is that clear from this sentence?

Yes, but the subject is ommitted here, let's restore it:

> (我)好久没有看望萧乾老人了，(我)怕干扰他翻译和写作，(我)怕影响他休养生息，但(我)心里却常惦念着他。

This is verbose indeed, so it's natural to ommit it, especially in the writing at the view of first person.

`萧乾老人` is the object of `看望`, means `the aged named 萧乾`.

Comment: The bits Chinese leaves out always get me confused!

Answer (score 2):

That is the author of this article who hasn't visited 萧乾老人 for long time. the subject is omitted by the author

老人 is a respective form of address for elderly people.